# How to Get Object based response in Restkit 0.20.3

Tags: ios, restkit

Hi have used restkit in my several previous projects with version 0.10.0. But now i am going to move with new restkit v0.20.3.

I followed all the steps from upgrading 10.0 to 20.0 from [HERE](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Upgrading-from-v0.10.x-to-v0.20.0).

I am able execute my request and response also came under success blog. But i can get the property of my response object. That is very shocking for now. I can get value only by `[data valueForKey:@""]` which is not good i guess in restkit.

Can any one tell me about how we get value from object's property.

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)mappingResult.array.count);
        DataForResponse *data = [mappingResult.array objectAtIndex:0];
        User *user = [data valueForKey:@"user"];

        User *user = [[data.user allObjects] firstObject];
        NSLog(@"%@",[user valueForKey:@"email"]);
        RKLogInfo(@"Load collection of Users: %@", mappingResult.array);
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseString);
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
    }];
```

My goal is to get value of email like from `user.email`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching & based on my restkit knowledge below code is worked.

```
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[DataForResponse objectMappingForDataResponse:LOGIN] method:RKRequestMethodPOST pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"data" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
    [rkomForLogin addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
    RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[ responseDescriptor ]];
    operation.targetObject =  data;

    [rkomForLogin postObject:nil path:@"login" parameters:dict success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        // Handled with articleDescriptor
        NSLog(@"%@",operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseString);
        DataForResponse *data  = [mappingResult.array objectAtIndex:0];
        User *user  = [[data.user allObjects] firstObject];
        NSLog(@"%@",[user email]);
        NSLog(@"%ld",operation.HTTPRequestOperation.response.statusCode);
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // Transport error or server error handled by errorDescriptor
        NSLog(@"%@",operation.HTTPRequestOperation.responseString);
        RKLogError(@"Operation failed with error: %@", error);
    }];
```

This is same object based response that i was getting in restkit 0.10 so this is way to execute a request.